# awk and regex with {}

Tags: regex, awk

I want to print whole record if it contain word and some character, which are optional. Script:

```
/mount[ein]{0,2}/{
print $0}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Without "{" and "}" it work. I tried with "\" befor "{":

```
/mount[ein]\{0,2\}/{
    print $0}
```

Other example. For file:

```
mountx
mounte
mountee
mounteee
```

Awk:

```
awk '/mount[ein]{0,2}$/' file
```

And result:

//nothing

System:
Debian 7.8
Linux ibm 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Show your input and desired output.

Comment: Input is a text (part of book). I only want to know why regex doesn't work. Are {} don't work in awk.

Comment: What makes you believe the regex doesn't work? Without telling the input, the expected output and the actual output, it's hard for us to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression works with both a POSIX compliant `awk` and GNU `awk`.

Given the fact the the characters `e`, `i`, and `n` must be present from zero to three times but that there is no further constraint, this part can be removed from the pattern as `mount` followed by anything or nothing does match anyway. The action (`print $0`) being also the default one need not to be specified.

Your command can then be simplified to:

```
awk '/mount/'
```

Should you want the range to be used, you need to specify something after it, here is an example:

```
$ cat input
foo
mountx
mounte
mountee
mounteee
$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '/mount[ein]{0,2}$/' input
mounte
mountee
```

That is on Solaris where the POSIX `awk` is in `/usr/xpg4/bin`.

Same behavior on the Debian based Mint 17.1:

```
$ awk -V | head -1      
GNU Awk 4.0.1
$ awk '/mount[ein]{1,2}$/' input     
mounte
mountee
```

However, it looks like `mawk`, which claims POSIX compliance, doesn't support the interval (brace) expression.

```
$ mawk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan
$ mawk '/mount[ein]{1,2}$/' input
$
```

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=355442).

Comment: I copied your input and command, but in my Debian it does't work. But without "{}" awk show the result, so maybe there is something wrong with my OS?

Comment: Again, please explain what you mean with "it doesn't work", i.e. the actual command run, its input, its expected output and its actual output.

Comment: I am sorry. Output is not this what I suspect. I think it's because of regex, because I try other without "{}".
Yesterday I check the same script on other system (Slackware) and it's work, so I think there is something wrong with my Debian.

Even I copy your script and Debian showed nothing,

Comment: Please edit your question with the requested details : What version of awk  you are running on that Debian, what output do you get with what command and what input.

Comment: A reason for the command not to output anything might be the input lines are ended with CRLF (Windows style) vs LF (Unix style). Try `awk '/mount[ein]{1,2}\r$/' input `

Comment: It doesn't work too. Maybe it's something with configuration?

Comment: You might be using `mawk` which indeed doesn't support this syntax. See my updated answer.

Comment: mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
Can I change it?

Comment: Yes, I figure it it in the meantime. Install GNU awk to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Example tst.txt:

```
mountx
mounte
mountee
mounteee
```

awk (GNU Awk 3.1.7) script

```
awk --re-interval '/mount[ein]{0,2}$/' tst.txt > tst1.txt
```

result

```
mounte
mountee
```

man awk

```
-W re-interval
--re-interval
          Enable the use of interval expressions in regular expression matching (see Regular Expressions, below).  Interval expressions were not traditionally available in the AWK
          language.  The POSIX standard added them, to make awk and egrep consistent with each other.  However, their use is likely to break old AWK programs, so  gawk  only  pro-
          vides them if they are requested with this option, or when --posix is specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your mount command format, and the question is listed as a "awk" question, with no awk in your comment.

Is this what you're looking for?

"print all lines that contain a 0" (or whatever string you're searching for)
from a file - use the command

```
cat temp.txt | grep 0 | awk '{print $0}'
```

will result in

> 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
>
> 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8

where temp.txt is

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
>
> 9 8 7 6 5 4
>
> 8 7 6 5 4 3
>
> 7 6 5 4 3
>
> 6 5 4 3
>
> 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 2

Comment: Result is ok, but I have to write it entirely in awk script and I don't know why "{}" doesn't work.Do you know why my regex doesn't work?

Comment: Not without knowing what /mount[ein] is

Comment: "mount" <- this is the word, which is constant, but characters e i n can be in line, but don't have to and 3 characters (e i n) can be repeated zero, one or two times.